# Multiple conditional percentile

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wanted to do a conditional quartile formula using two conditions instead of just one condition that is to be TRUE when both are TRUE:

```
      val   crit  perc   cond
0.415605498 1     perc1  1
0.475426007 1     perc1  2
0.418621318 1     perc2  3
0.51608229  1     perc1  1
```

I tried such formula using ctrl+shift+enter:

```
=QUARTILE(IF(AND(perc="perc1";cond=1);value;""),0)
```

But it didn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array formulas do not like `AND`.

So either:

```
=QUARTILE(IF((perc="perc1")*(cond=1);val),0)
```

with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Or this entered normally

```
=AGGREGATE(17;6;val/((perc="perc1")*(cond=1));0)
```

Comment: Great! This is what I was searching for :)

Comment: What is going on here with 17 and 6 in your AGGREGATE - specifically in relation to question...

Comment: @JGFMK see Microsoft's page: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df

Comment: OK. Cheers. Excel should use enumerations instead of magic numbers!